# How to resize iFrame and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How do I resize an iframe like an image though keep the site in view as if it were being seen from a desktop.

Example: https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/massively/

https://jsfiddle.net/f13z5mtn/

The example becomes the mobile site in the JSFiddle, how do we keep the site as if it was being viewed from a desktop?

I have tried applying:

```
zoom: 0.x
```

Of different amounts on different elements though is there a more unified way of achieving this?

Comment: An iframe has it's own window. Width of that window determines media queries used inside it. If you control that code you would need different rules when the iframe window is not the parent page window. If it is a cross origin iframe you can't do anything inside it

Comment: @charlietfl I do have control of the iframe code, what could I add so that it can be "zoomed out" with the same aspect ratio?

Comment: could add a class to body when `window !== window.top` which will be true inside an iframe since top window is the main page window. Then would need to manage all the style rules accordingly based on that additional parent class